# Export data from Excel to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, office365, azure-table-storage, excel-2016

I have a ASP.NET WebApp that manages some `Records`. The Records are kept in a Azure Table Storage tables.

The client gave me an Excel file with some hundred of `Records` in Excel table format (Fields in Columns).

How can I export that table from Excel to Azure Table? I saw there is a way to import data **from** Azure Tables into Office 2016 Excel (via `Data>DetData>FromAzure`) but I'd like to know if there are ways to do it backward(from Excel to Azure), and perhaps apply a custom logic when exporting that data (like manage DateTime or transform enumerations...).

I would like to import at least the string fields that does not need transformations, then I would do the rest manually or by code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- Using the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer) you can import / export data to and from table storage using CSV files.
- Upload the file to blob storage and use [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-table-connector) to transform and import the data.
- Write [some code](https://gist.github.com/miso-soup/7028c89165de4652cb50) to do this.

An addition about the transform part: you might be able to do this in the source excel file as well. In that case option 1 is probably the easiest.

When it comes to option 1, you can choose to use a .typed.csv file or a regular one. Using the latter it will try to distill the type. So importing a .csv file looking like this:

> PartitionKey,RowKey,C1,C2
>
> a,a,1,w
>
> a,b,2,ww
>
> a,c,5,www

will result in a table with 4 columns. (Actually, there will be five, the Timestamp column you'll get for free)

Comment: If I understand well, the is Azure Data Factory is not free... Some code woud be great, if I'll use that import recursively... but is not the case... do probably I will go with the the first option... However, to format the CSV could be also complicated, the azure imports needs a specific format that specifies the type of each field...

Comment: You do not need to use a specific format. If you don't it will guess the type based on the file content

Comment: For the record, you pay only for the usage when using Azure Data Factory. For a job like this it won't cost much, but that is up to you to decide :-)

Comment: Another problem I meet, French Excel does not export CSV as Coma separated values, but as Semicolon Separated values... so Azure does not understand it :D OK.... not so simple for non-americans :)

Comment: Yeah I know. Read [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8eeddfc8-9683-417b-ae29-14c04fd9b8a9/excel-2013-export-csv-with-comma-delimiter) or open the file in notepad and replace ; with , Amazing how they made in so difficult in Excel. Almost worth a new question ;-)

Comment: is not so simple to replace ";" with ",", because it uses another *string separator* as well, by eg if the cell content is like "A,B" is exported as `,"A,B",`, or `;A,B;`... I finally found out the problem, I should not only replace the *list separator* with `,`, but also the decimal one with `.`, only then it worked :)

Comment: Another problem Azure Explorer does not import the `,002,` nor `,"002",` values as text, it transforms it in integers...

Comment: Should specify the type with by eg `,Technology,Technology@type,` in column name and then `,007,Edm.String,` in values :)

Comment: When importing the file, doesn't it show a dialog with detected column types? you can change it there.

Comment: see my previous comment... the select works, but afraid it will ask me for each line ...